# Can't capitalize first letter, element not updated

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am getting my string from a textBox like this (in a loop where index is incremented):

```
var name = document.getElementById("TextBox" + index).value;
```

And I have a function in my script that looks like this meant to uppercase first letter:

```
function capital(string)
{
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

And try to use it like this:

```
var name = document.getElementById("TextBox" + index).value;
capital(name);
```

They are in different functions in the same `script` tag. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: well at face value this seems legit.. where are you trying to actually apply the change, the returned result of `capital(name)` ?

Comment: Are you trying to `getElementById` using the input type, or do you  have actual IDs on your textbox called 'TextBox'?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you assign the modified value back to the control:

```
var element = document.getElementById("TextBox" + index);
var name = element.value;
element.value = capital(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

String are immutable in js, you need to reassign.

```
var name = capital(document.getElementById("TextBox" + index).value);
```

Plus strings are passed by value, so they are copied over to the new function. So whatever you do in the function won't cause any effects in your name variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to getElementById using the input type, or do you have actual IDs on your textbox called 'TextBox'? The below works fine, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vRDzm/)

```
var index = 1;

var name = document.getElementById("test" + index).value;

function capital(str)
{
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
}

alert(capital(name));
```